# Ansible group vars on specific host

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I try to push specific conf with *group_vars*, but it only make push for one instance **aa.yml** and I don't have the push for **bb.yml** inventory. I already used group_vars and works before, but not with conf ansible

```
- name: Push conf
  uri:
    url: "https://xxx{{ instance_id }}"
    method: POST
    status_code: [201]
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
    body_format: json
    body: "{\"server\":{{ server }},\"labels\":{{{ site }}},\"name\":\"{{ instance.value.name }}"
    return_content: true
  vars:
    instance: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ instances }}"
```

inventory/host/group_vars/aa/aa.yml

```
site: "\"aa\""
instance_id: "06a56590"
server: "[\"server1\"]"
```

inventory/host/group_vars/bb/bb.yml

```
site: "\"bb\""
instance_id: "bcc37660"
server: "[\"server2\"]"
```

inventory/host/000_hosts

```
[host]
server1
server2
```

The command:

```
ansible-playbook task.yml -i inventory/host/000_hosts --extra-vars "target=host"
```

Comment: Does this even work? 

You're defining `aa` and `bb` as group variables by creating their own distinct directory, but these groups are nowhere to be found in your inventory. Don't your two hosts (`server1` and  `server2`) need to be part of their own distinct groups, in this case `aa` and `bb`, which again are children of the group `host`?

Comment: thanks for your replyin, but I don't understand what I can do :(

Comment: Could it be possible to apply a little more information ? After run playbook, and values of `instances` variable

Answer (score 1):

Supplying with an answer:
`group_vars/XXX` directories typically refers to groups defined in your inventory, and they contain variables only available for that group.  In your case you created directories for the groups `aa` and `bb`, these groups does not exists in your inventory, meaning when you call your playbook referring to your hosts (`- hosts: host`), ansible will look for group variables related to that group. Which is this case does not exists.

As you will see in my suggestion below; by using the keyword `children` in your inventory, you are basically saying: The hosts defined in the group `aa`/`bb` is part/children of the group `host` (the parent), and the variables follows. ([inheriting-variable-values-group-variables-for-groups-of-groups)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inheriting-variable-values-group-variables-for-groups-of-groups)

Changing your inventory to the following, should solve the problem:
*inventory/host/hosts*

```
[aa]
server1
[bb]
server2
[host:children]
aa
bb
```

You could also change your directory structure to something like:

```
inventory/
├── group_vars
│   ├── aa
│   │   └── aa.yml
│   └── bb
│       └── bb.yml
└── hosts
```

**Edit:**
However, if I'm not mistaken: your `hosts` directory (in `inventory/hosts`) is typically used to identify your environment like:
[Multistage environment Ansible](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-multistage-environments-with-ansible)

```
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── environments/         # Parent directory for our environment-specific directories
│   │
│   ├── dev/              # Contains all files specific to the dev environment
│   │   ├── group_vars/   # dev specific group_vars files
│   │   │   ├── all
│   │   │   ├── db
│   │   │   └── web
│   │   └── hosts         # Contains only the hosts in the dev environment
│   │
│   ├── prod/             # Contains all files specific to the prod environment
│   │   ├── group_vars/   # prod specific group_vars files
│   │   │   ├── all
│   │   │   ├── db
│   │   │   └── web
│   │   └── hosts         # Contains only the hosts in the prod environment
│   │
│   └── stage/            # Contains all files specific to the stage environment
│       ├── group_vars/   # stage specific group_vars files
│       │   ├── all
│       │   ├── db
│       │   └── web
│       └── hosts         # Contains only the hosts in the stage environment
│
├── playbook.yml
│
└── . . .
```

Take a look at [organizing-host-and-group-variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables)

Comment: Thanks for your explication, but does not change something :( Still one server changed and not the second one

Comment: I tried to create a simple web server and `POST` to it, using your quotations; it worked only on one of the server, why? I'm not sure. So I ended up changing your quotations in `body` to e.q `'{"instance": "{{ instance_id  }}", "site": "{{ site }}", "instances": {{ server  }}'`, and removed the outer `"` in the `group_vars/`  files, then it worked.